# Does uWSGI need to be restarted when Django code changes?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm working on a Django webapp that's running under nginx and uWSGI.  When I deploy new Django code (e.g., settings.py), do I need to restart uWSGI?  If so, why?

Background: I had a scenario where I updated settings.py and some other code and deployed it.  I did not see the changes in the webapp behavior until I restarted uWSGI.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you need to restart the uWSGI process.

Python keeps the compiled code in memory so it won't get re-read until the process restarts. The django development server (`manage.py runserver`) actively monitors files for changes, but that won't happen by default with other servers.  If you want to enable automatic reloading in uWSGI, the [touch-reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload) and [py-auto-reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#py-auto-reload) uWSGI arguments might help.