# uwsgi error log show flask TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

i am learning to write python flask code.
My flask application use owm web server is OK. Howerver, Using nginx+uwsgi+flask deploy, uwsgi error:

```
    [2018-09-05 18:28:59,295] ERROR in app: Exception on /editor [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1831, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1957, in make_response
    'The view function did not return a valid response. The'
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

my flask code is flaskr example. the code is as follows:

```
# coding=utf-8
"""
    ~~~~~~
    A microblog example application written as Flask tutorial with
    Flask and sqlite3.
    :copyright: (c) 2010 by Armin Ronacher.
    :license: BSD, see LICENSE for more details.
"""

from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash


# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE='/tmp/flaskr.db',
    DEBUG=False,
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)


def connect_db():
    print ("connect db")
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv


def init_db():
    """Creates the database tables."""
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
            print("excute sql")
        db.commit()


def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()


@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

@app.route('/editor')
def editor():
    print ("editor")
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Other view function is ok.Only edtior view function is error. but only run flask is ok. Adding nginx and uwsgi is error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restart the uswgi, the editor view function worked. Maybe because uwsgi can't detect the the change of python code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121844/does-uwsgi-need-to-be-restarted-when-django-code-changes